# Write validation failed for table row of type 'PurchPurchaseOrderLineEntity'

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations, dynamics-ax7

I'm trying to post the the purchase order line details from postman using odata and I'm getting the following error.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "Write validation failed for table row of type 'PurchPurchaseOrderLineEntity'. Infolog: .",
        "type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.AxODataValidateWriteException",
        "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.UpdateProcessor.CreateEntity_Save(ChangeOperationContext context, ChangeInfo changeInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.UpdateManager.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<CreateEntity>b__1(ChangeOperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.ChangeInfo.ExecuteActionsInCompanyContext(IEnumerable`1 actionList, ChangeOperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.ChangeInfo.TrySave(ChangeOperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.UpdateManager.SaveChanges()\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.AxODataDelegatingHandler.<SaveChangesAsync>d__3.MoveNext()"
    }
}
```

}

I have tried checking these links but I'm not getting a breakthrough:

- https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/Error-creating-order-line-in-Dynamics-365-for-Operations/td-p/11927
- https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/378486/error-while-submitting-po-from-external-system-odata-d365-f-o

Below is my payload

```
{      
            "dataAreaId": "XXXX",
            "LineNumber": 1,
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "XXXX-PO-000009",
            "ReceivingSiteId": "1",
            "LineDescription": "XXXXXXX XXXX XXXX",
            "ItemNumber": "SKU0000012530",
            "DIOTOperationType": "Blank",
            "LineAmount": 9687.19,
            "PurchasePriceQuantity": 1,
            "PurchasePrice": 9687.19,
            "PurchaseUnitSymbol": "EA",
            "OrderedPurchaseQuantity": 1,
            "DeliveryAddressName": "XXXXX XXXXX XXXX",
            "ProcurementProductCategoryName": "XXXXXX XXXXX XXXX",
            "ReceivingWarehouseId": "TG",
            "VendorInvoiceMatchingPolicy": "ThreeWayMatch",
            "RequestedDeliveryDate": "2021-09-03T12:00:00Z"
}
```

Anyone who can help me on this?

**NB**: The Purchase order header is working without any problem.

Comment: `PurchPurchaseOrderLineEntity` has `validateWrite` method, try debugging it or at least make sure your data is valid

Comment: Hi @AliaksandrMaksimau, I have tried to uncheck the ValidateField method in Data Management, but still bringing the same results.

Comment: I'm talking about `validateWrite` method, not `validateField`. I cannot add a screenshot to the comment here, but if you open it in the AOT you will see that there are some checks that can cause this error

Comment: Unfortunately, the `innererror` part of the error message cuts off after where it says "Infolog: ", which would probably contain information about why the validation failed. You can try to import your payload with a data project instead to see if it has the same issue. Hopefully, you can then find the full infolog in one of the logs of the data project. Otherwise, please [edit] your question to add the information what version you are using, if there are customizations and if you are using Contoso demo data. This gives us a chance to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the missing information in the question, I tried to reproduce the issue. My test setup was a 10.0.20 environment with contoso demo data. I used the DEMF company and created a new purchase order since the existing ones were either already invoiced and/or intercompany.

I created the new purchase order for vendor DE-001 and was able to create lines in it using an OData request sent by Postman.

While testing, I noticed that the response Postman receives does contain the infolog messages which are missing in the question. Either they were removed (in which case please [edit] the question and add them) or the version of D365 does not include them (in which case please [edit] the question to add the version information).

I also noticed that the payload in the question contains fields `ItemNumber` and `ProcurementProductCategoryName`. As far as I know, a purchase line can have only one of those two, but not both. If you manually create a line with either one, the other one will be locked for editing. So please retry your request without either the `ItemNumber` or the `ProcurementProductCategoryName` field.

For the record, here are the payloads that worked in my test setup:

Payload with procurement category

```
{      
            "dataAreaId": "DEMF",
            "LineNumber": 1,
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "000011",
            "ReceivingSiteId": "1",
            "LineDescription": "XXXXXXX XXXX XXXX",
            "ProcurementProductCategoryName": "PAYROLL",
            "DIOTOperationType": "Blank",
            "LineAmount": 47.11,
            "PurchasePriceQuantity": 1,
            "PurchasePrice": 47.11,
            "PurchaseUnitSymbol": "EA",
            "OrderedPurchaseQuantity": 1,
            "DeliveryAddressName": "XXXXX XXXXX XXXX",
            "ReceivingWarehouseId": "11",
            "VendorInvoiceMatchingPolicy": "ThreeWayMatch",
            "RequestedDeliveryDate": "2021-09-03T12:00:00Z"
}
```

Payload with item number

```
{      
            "dataAreaId": "DEMF",
            "LineNumber": 1,
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "000009",
            "ReceivingSiteId": "1",
            "LineDescription": "XXXXXXX XXXX XXXX",
            "ItemNumber": "D0001",
            "DIOTOperationType": "Blank",
            "LineAmount": 47.11,
            "PurchasePriceQuantity": 1,
            "PurchasePrice": 47.11,
            "PurchaseUnitSymbol": "EA",
            "OrderedPurchaseQuantity": 1,
            "DeliveryAddressName": "XXXXX XXXXX XXXX",
            "ReceivingWarehouseId": "11",
            "VendorInvoiceMatchingPolicy": "ThreeWayMatch",
            "RequestedDeliveryDate": "2021-09-03T12:00:00Z"
}
```

Comment: Good job going the extra mile!